# JSENCODE incorrect argument type

Tags: javascript, error-messages, actionfunction

I have the following issue:

```
var accountScheduler = "{!JSENCODE(Account.Number_Of_Due_Days__c)}";
```

Upon initializing the `accountScheduler` variable I receive the following error:

> Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'JSENCODE()'.

Could you please advise what could be the reason and how to avoid such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see `Number_Of_Due_Days__c` is a Number where as `JSENCODE` accepts a text/String. Thus you have to convert the Number into Text.

```
var accountScheduler = "{!JSENCODE(Account.Number_Of_Due_Days__c.toString())}";
```

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5

Comment: `{!JSENCODE(TEXT(Account.Number_Of_Due_Days__c))}` you mean.

Comment: Is it even required to jsencode a number field?